# data erased reappear when i pressed the back button Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I have 2 views and a navigationController. The first, adds data in an array. This datas are displayed in my second view (is a tableviewController). I can erase some data in my array directly from my tableView, and I remove a row at the same time.
When I pressed the back button, and I try to add a new data, when my second view appear, I see my data news datas, and the data erased... I don't understand.
From the view 1 to view 2, I have the "prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)" function.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.

Let's say you have an array called `data` in the first view controller, and you pass this array to the second view controller when navigating to it. When you pass this array, it gets copied. The `data` array in second view controller is an array different from `data` array in first view controller.

So changes applied to `data` array of the second view controllers do not affect `data` array of first view controller.

To make these changes make effect on first view controller you need to change `data` array of first view controller somehow; you can use delegates or callbacks for example.

Comment: Fisrt, thank you Moe for you answer.
So, my problem was not the back button, and my data saved. The problem was, that i tired to use "manager calss" for my objet, and i used this wrong.
In my first view, i instancied this manager (in this one, i have all my functions to erase, and add item). To pass from the view 1 to my view 2 (uiTableViewController) i used the prepare for segue function. In this function, i passed my array, but i didin't knw i passed too my instance of my "manager". In the view 2, i instancied too my "manager". So, i had 2 instance of the same "manager". It was the problem

Comment: Oh I see, great you found the solution.